# Is ArchBang just Arch Linux + Openbox?

Tags: arch-linux

I'm a Arch + KDE guy. I need to reinstall frequently, and I don't like that when I do `pacman -S kde` I have to wait like two hours (slow Internet) without using the PC.

So I'm looking for an Arch based distro, but just Arch + a WM or DE; nothing more like Chakra does. Is ArchBang just Arch Linux + Openbox ?

Answer (score 6):

No, Archbang is **not** Arch Linux. The Archbang developers have consistently made decisions that mean Archbang differs from Arch.

Initially it was around things that could be considered "convenience"<sup>1</sup>, like installing from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) by default, by default including files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` or having a keybind for `pacman -Syyuuf`.

Over time, and particularly with Arch's recent move to systemd, the differences have become much more marked; to the point where now the Archbang developer is musing about [using a Slackware base](http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?pid=18855#p18855).

If you want to install Arch, [install Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/download/); but don't be misled into thinking that by installing Archbang you are going to be running Arch Linux.

<sup>1. Note, none of these things is, from an Arch point of view, either convenient or a particularly good idea, and the last of the three can only be described as reckless.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

More or less, with some usability modifications. However, please bear in mind that requests for support when using ArchBang or Chakra are often summarily rejected in help fora that have an Arch Linux context (ArchBang and other Arch Linux derivatives are not considered be to within the remit of Arch Linux support by most).

Comment: I didn't undestand most of the answer because my English is a bit bad... but you mean that the Arch Community is not going to help me if I use ArchBang or that the Arch support is not going to work in ArchBang ? If is the 1st, can't I just tell it's Arch ?

Comment: The first. It isn't Arch, so you shouldn't mislead people. If they find out you are using ArchBang when you are claiming to use Arch, you will likely be cast out (I've seen it happen multiple times).

Comment: ok; I will install Arch... but I said I just installed it two times... I just want a quick way to install it.
Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference between ArchBang and vanilla arch + openbox + a few odd AUR packages and some initial configuration. You can install ArchBang and remove all that stuff and you'll just have Arch.
You use exactly the same mirrors as Arch linux, the same AUR as Arch Linux users, and the same package manager as Arch.
The only difference is that the installation media will install some additional packages and some configuration done for you.

If the Arch Forums are "casting out" users for asking questions that aren't specific to the ArchBang installation media and initial config because they happened to install Arch via an ArchBang installation medium... that is quite bizarre.

Comment: An actually useful answer.

Answer (score -2):

as OliJG said it is absolutely the same.

BUT

I would say ArchBang is the system of ONE arch user.
This auto-configuration and not being able to choose everything yourself and be not included into the system (your thoughts and preferences) is totally 
against The Arch Way !!
that might be the reason Arch fora kick ArchBang-users out.

Comment: No, the reason that Archbang is not supported on the Arch boards is because, for the reasons I described in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53586/6761), it is not practicable for our community to support derivative distributions.